# VS How to Add custom code snippet automatically when I create new method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a c# class library for my debugging purpose where I will create methods whenever I need to do something.

Each and every method I need to append to the try catch and some other code snippet automatically. Say for ex. as below, when I create a new method, the try/catch and the snippet inside should be created automatically for each and every method when I create.

Any idea how I can do this?

```
public static void MyMethod1()
{
try
{       
    string loggerFileName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe [templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820614.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is what you are looking for. If you are using Resharper it's [code templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_templates.html) are very powerful and customizable.

Comment: Did you try creating your own Visual Studio Snippets? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you want to write a custom visual studio code snippet. I just took some different snippet and modified it to your request... <strike>it's not tested, so may need some minor changes in order to work.</strike> just tested it, working like a charm for me.

Create a `test.snippet` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>Test Method</Title>
            <Author>Grek40</Author>
            <Description>Create a testmethod with initial body</Description>
            <Shortcut>test</Shortcut>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>name</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Replace with the testmethod name</ToolTip>
                    <Default>TestMethod</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="CSharp">
                <![CDATA[
                public static void $name$()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string loggerFileName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString();

                        $end$
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Then install it in VS Tools - Snippet Manager.

Use it as writing `test` <kbd>TAB</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> `YourActuallyDesiredMethodName` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks grek40. It works for me. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about

1. Writing `svm` and then press <kbd>TAB</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> (creates static method)
2. Writng `try`and then press <kbd>TAB</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> (creates try-catch block)

The result should look like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

A new method with try-catch in 10 keystrokes :)

Comment: Thanks Smartis. I am aware of this 2.Writng tryand then press TAB+TAB (creates try-catch block)